# Obj-c Xcode static analysis produces a "Dereference of null pointer" on pointer assignment

Tags: objective-c, xcode, static-analysis, objective-c-runtime

I am trying to implement a tricky thing: all my model classes have an automatic NSCoding implementation of their properties. This let me add and remove properties to my classes and do not worry about missing stuff being not encoded/decoded. (Actually, it serves also other purposes, but that's the main idea).

When initializing my object from archive with initWithCoder, thanks to the Obj-C runtime, I go through the list of my properties, and try to assign directly the ivars to the values. I do not want to go through setters for various and imperious reasons, hence setValue:forKey: is forbidden.

Interesting problem, isn't it? I must say I am not full confident with C-pointers subtleties...

Here is the code:

```
unsigned int outCount;
objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList(class, &outCount);

for (unsigned int index = 0; index < outCount; index++) {
    objc_property_t property = properties[index];
    NSString *propertyNameString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:property_getName(property)];

    id value = [coder decodeObjectForKey:propertyNameString];
    if (value == nil) {
        continue;
    }

    const char *attributes = property_getAttributes(property);
    NSString *typeAttribute = [[NSString stringWithUTF8String:attributes] substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, 1)];
    const char *ivarName = [[@"_" stringByAppendingString:propertyNameString] UTF8String];

    if ([typeAttribute isEqualToString:@"@"]) {
        Ivar ivar = class_getInstanceVariable([self class], ivarName);
        object_setIvar(self, ivar, value);
    }
    else if ([typeAttribute isEqualToString:@"d"]) {
        double *doublePointer = getIvarPointer(self, ivarName);
        *doublePointer = [value doubleValue];
    }
    else if ([typeAttribute isEqualToString:@"i"]) {
        int *intPointer = getIvarPointer(self, ivarName);
        *intPointer = [value intValue];
    }
    else if ([typeAttribute isEqualToString:@"c"]) {
        char *charPointer = getIvarPointer(self, ivarName);
        *charPointer = [value boolValue];
    }
    else if ([typeAttribute isEqualToString:@"Q"]) {
        NSUInteger *uintegerPointer = getIvarPointer(self, ivarName);
        *uintegerPointer = [value unsignedIntegerValue];
    }
}

free(properties);
```

The 'getIvar' function looks like this (yes, I use class_getInstanceVariable on object class, since object_getInstanceVariable is not allowed with ARC...):

```
static void* getIvarPointer(id object, char const *name)
{
    Ivar ivar = class_getInstanceVariable(object_getClass(object), name);
    if (!ivar) return 0;
    return (unsigned char *)(__bridge void *)object + ivar_getOffset(ivar);
}
```

When running Xcode's static analyzer, I get a warning saying "**Dereference of null pointer (loaded from variable 'doublePointer')**". Interestingly enough, a similar message appeared for int and NSUInteger, but seems to have disappear right now... It never appeared for 'char'.

Any idea, suggestion or insightful criticism would be very much appreciated.

I must say that, the code actually works. I do get automatic decoding of double and int in my object classes. But I want to understand why the static analyzer tells me such thing.

Comment: Sidenote: the construction of the type string is **super inefficient.** Why don't you just `switch (attributes[0])`?

Comment: Thanks for the tip. No explanation, just habits of using Obj-C strings instead of C ones.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm one of those who learnt C separately before doing iOS development, so these tend to catch my attention :)

Comment: Is that so visible that I've been the other way round? ;-)

Comment: Yes, it's quite conspicuous :)

Answer (score 0):

As your getIvarPointer() function can legibly return 0, you must handle this eventuality in each *ptr affectation I think.
For example:

```
if ([typeAttribute isEqualToString:@"d"]) {
    double *doublePointer = getIvarPointer(self, ivarName);
    if (doublePointer) {
        *doublePointer = [value doubleValue];
    } else {
        // Handle this as you can ;)
    }
}
```

Comment: Very good point indeed, I'll correct. But it still doesn't explain why it doesn't pops up on *charPointer, right?

Comment: Clang generally tries to not duplicate errors;  if one failure will cause a cascade of problems, it'll try to only display the first.   Sometimes it screws up in this.  This may be a screwup or, if it is intelligent enough to do cross-function-boundary flow analysis, it may be squelching under the assumption you'll fix the function.  I.e. it could easily be a bug and, if you were feeling motivated, you could explore the circumstances where it happens and file it!